# Rider Error : unknown error

Tags: rider

I am just starting using Rider.

I want to start my HelloWorld console Application.

But the build fails with Error : `Error:: unknown error`.

If I click on the error, I see the csprojFile of my project with one error and one warning.

The error is on this line :

```
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

It complains about the property `xmlns` and says : `Uri is not registred`

The warning is for the variable `$(MSBuildToolsVersion)` : `Property MSBuildToolsVersion is not registred`

**EDIT**

We an interesting error in the Event Log :

```
ReSharperHostException
        Can't find msbuild with version 4.0
        ...
```

Any idea?

Comment: It seems I am not the first one to have this issue! https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-1471

Comment: According to the bug tracker the issue you linked is fixed. Do you still experience it after installing EAP 8?